# Unable to build ionic app on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: android-studio, ionic-framework, gradle

I am building my ionic app in ubuntu 20.04, I installed android studio, added the required build tools, and also installed ionic and cordova. But when I attempt to build my app using the command below

```
ionic cordova build android
```

I get the following error

```
Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle 
in your path, or install Android Studio
```

I check the installed version of gradle using `gradle -v` and I get the following result

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.0
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2021-04-09 22:27:31 UTC
Revision:     d5661e3f0e07a8caff705f1badf79fb5df8022c4

Kotlin:       1.4.31
Groovy:       3.0.7
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
JVM:          1.8.0_282 (Private Build 25.282-b08)
OS:           Linux 5.8.0-50-generic amd64
```

When I also check for the path using `whereis gradle`, I get the following result

```
gradle: /opt/gradle/gradle-7.0/bin/gradle.bat /opt/gradle/gradle-7.0/bin/gradle
```

When I run `ionic info` I get the result below

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.13.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.3.2
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1000.8
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 10.0.8
   @angular/cli                  : 10.0.8
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI   : 2.4.1
   @capacitor/core : 2.4.1

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 20 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.3
   native-run  : not installed

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/home/evans/Android/Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v10.19.0 (/usr/bin/node)
   npm               : 7.11.1
   OS                : Linux 5.8
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Could you post the output of `ionic info`

Comment: I have added the output.